# Generics with same base class

Tags: java, generics

I have a TreeNode class defined like so:

```
class TreeNode<T extends MyClass> {
    public T element;
    public TreeNode<? extends MyClass> parent;
    public ArrayList<TreeNode<? extends MyClass>> children;
}
```

I would like to know if there is an easier way to restrict all TreeNodes to generic type variables that extend `MyClass`? Having to write out `ArrayList<TreeNode<? extends MyClass>>` is very tedious. I can't just do `ArrayList<TreeNode<T>>` because then the Tree cannot contain nodes with a different inheritance of MyClass.

I tried to do something like this:
`public static const Class NODE_CLASS = TreeNode<? extends TreeNode>.class;` but I don't think you can use generics as part of a class object.

Someting synonymous to C++'s `typedef` I guess, I.e.
`typedef TreeNode<? extends MyClass> NodeClass;`

Comment: To be honest I don't see the point of using generics if `T` doesn't match between nodes in a tree. Given that, `element` should just be `MyClass`.

Comment: Ahh yes of course, just make them all of the base type!

Comment: Just as a sidenote: I'd replace `ArrayList<...>` with just `List<...>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my comment seemed to help you, I'll post it as an answer:

I don't see the point of using generics if `T` doesn't match between nodes in a tree. Given that, `element` should just be `MyClass`.

Comment: That was the fastest upvote I've ever seen - how did you even do that?

Comment: I was on the page when it said "1 new answer" so I loaded and upvoted :P

Comment: Ha, from my POV it literally started with 1 vote. Wish all my answers did that :)

Comment: Hmm. Now I have an issue where I have to cast element constantly as I have classes that extend TreeNode for specific instances of MyClass.

Comment: Seems like a design issue. I would characterize the use of generics here as "take it or leave it". If a tree can be homogenous to a certain `T`, then use `TreeNode<T extends MyClass>` with `TreeNode<T> parent` and `List<TreeNode<T>> children`. Otherwise, yeah, casting is inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the generics you could shorten

```
ArrayList<TreeNode<? extends MyClass>> children;
```

to

```
List<TreeNode<?>> children;
```

Because the `extends MyClass` is stated in the class definition the compiler is still able to infer that only tree nodes with a parameter that extends `MyClass` (or `MyClass` itself) are allowed.

Just keep in mind that you's still have to use `MyClass` when accessing the element, since that's the only known common super class.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, repeating the bound of the type parameter (`T extends MyClass`) as the bound of the wildcard (`? extends MyClass`), does absolutely nothing. Just use the unbounded wildcard `?` (as in `TreeNode<?>`).

Comment: Does it not serve the purpose for someone else reading the code to realise that it can only contain nodes that extend MyClass? I'm not disputing you I'm just curious whether that would be a valid reason?

Comment: @Lerp if the user knows about class `TreeNode` she'd also know that there can't exist any instances where the parameter does _not_ extend `MyClass` (except when raw types are used).